# EXT JS - adding a listener on any element added to a container

Tags: extjs

HI,
I have a ExtJS parent 'container' type, whereas i need to add a 'contextmenu' listener to any element that is added to this parent container, via Drag/Drop.
Can someone guide me as to the best way to do this?

I have tried this below but can't get the function to fire.

```
myContainer.on('added', function(obj1,obj2,index){
   alert('added');
});
```

this may not be the 'best practice' to do it this way anyway...?
thanks for the help !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the wrong event... The `added` event gets fired when (using your example) `myContainer` is added to some other container. What you'll need is the `add` event that fires, when an item is added to `myContainer`:

```
myContainer.on('add', function(container, component, index) {
    component.on('contextmenu', function() {
    });
});
```